# How can I make Eclipse look like Textmate?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I'm *encouraged* to use a Linux box at work, so I'm using Eclipse for my coding. The default black on white theme is **horrible**, in my opinion. Is there any way I can get Twilight-style syntax coloring (for Javascript) in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3) has some excellent Textmate style features, including the Twilight theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a twilight theme for eclipse here:

https://the30minutesblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/twilight-color-theme-for-eclipse-ide/

It definitly works for the Java editor, but I havent tried for JS.

It probably depends on which JS plugin you are using.

Comment: That theme seems to work only with Java. Breaks [horribly](http://imgur.com/bHHqX.png) with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Preferences under **Window->Preferences**, then choose **General->Editor->Text Editors** and select the colors you prefer at the bottom of that page.